# How to grow a circle to cover the page and become a menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make one of those menus that is an offset circle, usually in the corner, and when you hover over it, it expands to become a full page menu.

Here is a portfolio that has a similar mechanism just for clarity: https://adrienlaurent.fr/

My biggest issue is I can't figure out what to Google, because "HTML expand circle to become a menu" isn't working.

I can offset the circle and I can make it fill the page. However, it looks terrible. even with the transition property, it's still jumpy. I am mostly using CSS animation but tried a few things in jQuery too.

```css
body {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .circle {
      background: orange;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 80vh;
      left: -2vw;
      transition: height 2s;
      transition: width 2s;
      transition: top 2s;
      transition: left 2s;
     
    }
    
    .circle:hover {
     height: 200vh;
     width: 200vw;
     top: -30vh;
     left: -30vw;
    }
```

```html
    
    <body>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    </body>
```

Again, any suggestions to make this a smoother transition would be fantastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would try:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  background: orange;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80vh;
  left: -2vw;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

ul {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .5s .5s;
}

li {
  color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu:hover .circle {
  transform: scale(20);
  top: -30vh;
  left: -30vw;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.menu:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s .5s;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Another menu link</li>
      <li>One more!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I added the `transition-duration` to both menu versions, so the transition works both ways. I transitioned `transform:scale` instead of width and height with 100vw/100vh in order to keep the circle perfectly round. You should not however put any other elements like menu lists into the same element if you want to use this approach, as the text will get transformed aswell and become really big.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I just started working with CSS animations so I'm doing little projects here and there. If I wanted to put a menu in there, how would I do that?

Comment: Check out my edit! I just put them in a separate element and added a wrapper `.menu` which I apply all hover effects to.

Answer (score 1):

instead of animating width, height, top or left, try looking into `transform` (better performance and you can set `transform-origin`). 
i don't know if this is what you want, but it should get you into the right direction

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  background: orange;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80vh;
  left: -2vw;
 transition: all .2s ease-out;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.circle:hover {
    transform: translateX(-50%) scale(2);
  
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="circle"></div>
</body>
```